# My HTML CSS website is displaying fine on my home computer but terribly on other screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, format

as the title states,

I am having trouble displaying my webpage properly on other screen resolutions.

I am not certain why it looks so bad on other screen resolutions and not scaling to the device itself.

I don't know exactly where to start, I would think that it has something to do with the way that I positioned my div containers but I am not too sure...

and would like a more experienced person to answer my question before I started messing with the code.

**below is my HTML, CSS code:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 140px 0px 140px;
  font-family: Rockwell;
}

#left_border {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 70px solid orange;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#right_border {
  position: relative;
  height: 220%;
  border-right: 70px solid orange;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

#header {
  background-color: Black;
  padding-bottom: 6%;
}

h1 {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Rockwell;
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

#positioning_a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 65%;
  top: 3.5%;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Rockwell;
}

#positioning_b {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70.5%;
  top: 3.5%;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Rockwell;
}

#positioning_c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.1%;
  left: 15.5%;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Rockwell;
}

#positioning_d {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.3%;
  left: 29.5%;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: Rockwell;
}

a[href^="mailto:"] {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: auto;
  left: 90%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

footer {
  background-color: Black;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.Right_Side {
  margin-left: 80%;
}

.Upwards {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.pretty {
  background-color: #0e76a8;
  color: White;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 42.5%;
  top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#footer {
  background-color: Black;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.weight {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Counter {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: 25px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<head>
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>
  <title> Online Resume </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header id="header">
      <h1> Noah Harris </h1>
      <h2>
        <div id="positioning_a"> Email: </div>
        <div id="positioning_b"> <a href="mailto:harrisspeed@gmail.com"> harrisspeed@gmail.com </a> </div>
        <div id="positioning_c"> Phone Number: </div>
        <div id="positioning_d"> 703-400-5998 </div>
      </h2>
  </div>
  </header>
  <div id="right_border">
    <div id="left_border">
      <img src="Badge.jpg" alt="Badge">
      <h3> About Me </h3>
      <p> Hello readers My name is Noah and I am partaking in the Cloud Resume Challenge <a href="https://cloudresumechallenge.dev/instructions/">To learn more about the challenge click here</a>. I have been studying Information Technology since i graduated
        highschool although I was not sure exactly what field I wanted to get into. I was able to get a IT helpdesk job which help me understand the fundamentals but i knew that i wanted to learn more. I later discovered the cloud and was intrigued by
        the freedom and creativity that could be expressed in the cloud. I began to get curious and that drove me to get my AWS Solutions Architect Associate. I am now working on more projects so that i can score real world experience and even have some
        fun with it. </p>
      <h3> Skills </h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="weight">Software:</div> Windows 7, 8 and 10; HTML and CSS knowledge. Experience using IDE’s with C++ and Python. Virtualization troubleshooting of virtual machines and VDI’s.</li>
        <br>
        <li>
          <div class="weight">Hardware:</div> Troubleshooting HP printers; general computer builds and repairs; hardware installations and swaps. RAID Arrays, RAM and CPU replacement. Ability to troubleshoot and narrow down problems regarding hardware </li>
        <br>
        <li>
          <div class="weight">Networking:</div> Networking experience (running cables, troubleshooting connections, activating ports, basic router configuration, switches, Wi-Fi router) Familiar with different cabling types such as CAT 5, CAT6, twisted pairs, fiber optic
          cables. </li>
        <br>
        <li>
          <div class="weight">Support:</div> Helpdesk: escalation and documentation on ticketing system, customer service support (email, phone, and in person). Assisting 40 customers per day. </li>
        <br>
        <li>
          <div class="weight">Cloud Computing:</div> Amazon Web Services, Cloud Architecture, Cloud Infrastructure. </li>
      </ul>
      <h3> Experience </h3>
      <div class="weight"> Navy Federal Credit Union </div>
      <div class="Right_Side Upwards weight"> Service Desk Member </div>
      <div class="weight"> Vienna, VA </div>
      <div class="Right_Side Upwards weight"> Feb 2018 - January 2021 </div>
      <ul>
        <li> Provided customer service to 30 customers a day. Talked to customers who needed technical support for their computers and active directory accounts. </li>
        <br>
        <li> Alerted management team when a technical outage in the credit union occurred to ensure that the issue gets patched as efficiently as possible. </li>
        <br>
        <li> Worked with colleagues in the event of a technical outage to minimize the call queue and effectively troubleshoot for a solution. </li>
      </ul>
      <h3> Education </h3>
      <p class="weight"> George Mason University </p>
      <div class="Right_Side Upwards weight"> Fairfax, Va </div>
      <div class="weight"> Information Technology </div>
      <div class="Right_Side Upwards weight" id="Upwards"> August 2017 - Present </div>
      <ul>
        <li> Year Up is a leading one-year career development program with 250 corporate partners around the country; the program includes college-level courses, professional training, and a six-month internship. </li>
        <br>
        <li> Earned an Associate Degree from Northern Virginia Community in Information Technology with 67 credits. </li>
        <br>
        <li> Working towards a bachelor's degree in Information Technology with 120 credits. </li>
      </ul>
      <h3> AWS Solutions Architecture </h3>
      <div class="weight"> Cloud Computing </div>
      <div class="Right_Side Upwards weight"> April 2021 </div>
      <ul>
        <li> Understands cloud architecture and how to host a highly available website. Able to write simple bash scripts on EC2 instances. </li>
        <br>
        <li> Able to execute best practices on security such as private subnets, firewalls, and security groups. </li>
        <br>
        <li> Understanding routing on Route 53 latency-based routing geolocation-based routing etc. </li>
        <br>
        <li> able to host a static website on S3. </li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">

    <div class="Counter">
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/noah-harris-947b38152/" class="pretty"> Check me out on Linkedin</a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: is best to use grid or flex just to be responsive :)

Comment: I will try to rewrite from zero your website, it can take less than 1 hour and I will answer to your answer... I know StackOverflow is not "we-are-doing-your-work.com" but I really want to help you!

Comment: almost finished (now started doing the education section)

Comment: finished the refactoring, do you want I will put it as an answer or give it the link of the , GitHub repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to follow many good techniques when developing a responsive webpage, here I explain to you:

- **Replacing in your CSS absolute units such as px for percentages or em**. It is always much better to work with relative measurements rather than absolute ones. From my experience, I always try to work with em, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_pxtoemconversion.asp) is a conversion from px to em.
- **Using responsive layouts like [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)**.
- **Adding metadata related to the viewport in the HTML head tag**. I can see you haven't written it. As we can read in W3Schools viewport is the user's visible area of a web page. It varies with the device so it will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen. You should include the following  element in all your web pages:
  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

In conclusion, try to avoid absolute positioning because it is not the best option. Try to follow this advice and I am sure your webpage will turn so much better. :D.

Answer (score 2):

I refactored all your code to be Responsive! with **CSS grid** and **flexbox**

not only CSS but also HTML to be `semantic`, easy to read...

---

the GitHub repo: https://github.com/Laaouatni/stackoverflow-my-answers/tree/main/79

---

try to see the @diego answer then copy this :)

I hope it will help you

**here the fixed complete code:**

```css
* {
    --linkedin-blue: #0e76a8;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#header div {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0.5vw;
}

#header a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#email-div>div:first-child,
#phone-div>div:first-child,
#header h1,
h3 {
    color: orange;
}

.container h3 {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}

.weight {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 5vw;
    padding: 2rem;
}

#skills ul,
#experience ul,
#education ul,
#aws-section ul {
    display: grid;
    gap: 0.5rem;
}

.space-between {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.vertical-gap {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.pretty {
    background-color: var(--linkedin-blue);
    color: White;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bg-orange {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<head>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
    <title> Online Resume </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <header id="header">
            <!-- 1- phone -->
            <div id="phone-div">
                <div>Phone Number:</div>
                <div>703-400-5998</div>
            </div>

            <!-- 2- main title -->
            <h1>Noah Harris</h1>

            <!-- 3- email -->
            <div id="email-div">
                <div>Email:</div>
                <div><a href="mailto:harrisspeed@gmail.com">harrisspeed@gmail.com</a></div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </nav>

    <div class="bg-orange">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- <img src="./Badge.jpg" alt="Badge"> -->

            <!-- about me -->
            <div id="aboutme">
                <h3>About Me</h3>
                <p> Hello readers My name is Noah and I am partaking in the Cloud Resume Challenge <a href="https://cloudresumechallenge.dev/instructions/">To learn more about the challenge click here</a>. I have been studying Information Technology since
                    i graduated highschool although I was not sure exactly what field I wanted to get into. I was able to get a IT helpdesk job which help me understand the fundamentals but i knew that i wanted to learn more. I later discovered the cloud
                    and was intrigued by the freedom and creativity that could be expressed in the cloud. I began to get curious and that drove me to get my AWS Solutions Architect Associate. I am now working on more projects so that i can score real
                    world experience and even have some fun with it.
                </p>
            </div>

            <!-- skills -->
            <section id="skills">
                <h3> Skills </h3>
                <ul>
                    <!-- 1 SOFTWARE-->
                    <li>
                        <div class="weight">Software:</div>
                        <span>
                            Windows 7, 8 and 10; HTML and CSS knowledge. Experience using IDE’s with C++ and Python. Virtualization troubleshooting of virtual machines and VDI’s.
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <!-- 2 HARDWARE -->
                    <li>
                        <div class="weight">Hardware:</div>
                        <span>
                            Troubleshooting HP printers; general computer builds and repairs; hardware installations and swaps. RAID Arrays, RAM and CPU replacement. Ability to troubleshoot and narrow down problems regarding hardware.
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <!-- 3 NETWORKING -->
                    <li>
                        <div class="weight">Networking:</div>
                        <span>
                            Networking experience (running cables, troubleshooting connections, activating ports, basic router configuration, switches, Wi-Fi router) Familiar with different cabling types such as CAT 5, CAT6, twisted pairs, fiber
                            optic cables.
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <!-- 4 SUPPORT -->
                    <li>
                        <div class="weight">Support:</div>
                        <span>Helpdesk: escalation and documentation on ticketing system, customer service support (email, phone, and in person). Assisting 40 customers per day.</span>
                    </li>
                    <!-- 5 CLOUD COMPUTING -->
                    <li>
                        <div class="weight">Cloud Computing:</div>
                        <span>Amazon Web Services, Cloud Architecture, Cloud Infrastructure.</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>


            <!-- experience -->
            <section id="experience">
                <h3> Experience </h3>

                <div class="vertical-gap">
                    <div class="space-between">
                        <div class="weight">Navy Federal Credit Union</div>
                        <div class="weight">Service Desk Member</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space-between">
                        <div class="weight">Vienna, VA</div>
                        <div class="weight">Feb 2018 - January 2021</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- LIST experience -->
                <ul>
                    <li>Provided customer service to 30 customers a day. Talked to customers who needed technical support for their computers and active directory accounts.</li>
                    <li>Alerted management team when a technical outage in the credit union occurred to ensure that the issue gets patched as efficiently as possible.</li>
                    <li>Worked with colleagues in the event of a technical outage to minimize the call queue and effectively troubleshoot for a solution.</li>
                </ul>
            </section>

            <!-- education -->
            <section id="education">
                <h3>Education</h3>

                <div class="space-between">
                    <p class="weight">George Mason University</p>
                    <div class="weight">Fairfax, Va</div>
                </div>
                <div class="space-between">
                    <div class="weight">Information Technology</div>
                    <div class="weight">August 2017 - Present</div>
                </div>

                <!-- LIST education -->
                <ul>
                    <li> Year Up is a leading one-year career development program with 250 corporate partners around the country; the program includes college-level courses, professional training, and a six-month internship. </li>
                    <li> Earned an Associate Degree from Northern Virginia Community in Information Technology with 67 credits. </li>
                    <li> Working towards a bachelor's degree in Information Technology with 120 credits. </li>
                </ul>
            </section>

            <!-- Amazon Web Services -->
            <section id="aws-section">
                <h3> AWS Solutions Architecture</h3>

                <div class="space-between">
                    <div class="weight"> Cloud Computing </div>
                    <div class="weight"> April 2021 </div>
                </div>

                <!-- LIST Amazon Web Services -->
                <ul>
                    <li> Understands cloud architecture and how to host a highly available website. Able to write simple bash scripts on EC2 instances. </li>
                    <li> Able to execute best practices on security such as private subnets, firewalls, and security groups. </li>
                    <li> Understanding routing on Route 53 latency-based routing geolocation-based routing etc. </li>
                    <li> able to host a static website on S3. </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>


    <footer id="footer">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/noah-harris-947b38152/" class="pretty">Check me out on Linkedin</a>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for checking my answer!!! I also want to thank you for refactoring all the code!!!

Comment: yep, completely agree with you!!

Comment: oh wow, i went to take a nap and I see that you went above and beyond my expectations for an answer. Thank you so much for pointing out how inflexible absolute positioning is. I wasn't sure if that was the issue but now I know for future webpages thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem I would advise that you read up on what `viewports` are on [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).

A viewport is basically the visible area on a user’s device.

As we both know, the visible area of a desktop is different from that of a notebook, tablet, and mobile phone.

The HTML, CSS you have displayed on your PC is not responsive to other viewports.

The way you can go about this is by writing the HTML and CSS in such a way that it will respond to all devices.

You need to use relative and absolute units like `em` and `%`, that way the code you have written will scale with respect to the viewport.

Media queries are also very functional. Media queries will help customize for a particular viewport.

W3schools.com will give you a great direction on these topics. I hope you enjoy yourself while learning.